# logout.php with access_token doesn't work any more

Tags: php, facebook, logout

We set up Facebook integration a few months ago, and everything has been fine until this week when logout has stopped working.

We use:

- JS sdk for identifying user
- Direct API calls from php (using `file_get_contents`) for most things

For logout, we log the user out of our App (including deleting cookies) then use javascript to redirect to this url:

```
"https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token=". $FB_ACCESS_TOKEN . "&next=" . urlencode($loginUrl)
```

That used to log the user out of facebook, then take them to our login page.

Now instead it leaves them logged in, and takes them to

```
https://www.facebook.com/home.php
```

Is this a facebook bug, or was I using a feature that wasn't ever intended for Apps to use? I'm guessing I can use the javascript API to get this working, just wanted to check if there was some small change I should make to my current way of doing it instead.

EDIT:

One other idea (if anyone knows) is that maybe there's been a change to the way permissions work, and I'm meant to be requesting an additional permission when the user logs in? At the moment I'm only asking for:

```
email,publish_actions
```

Comment: Apps are not meant to logout the user out of the site. They are only meant to log the user out of the app itself (aka, kill the session)

Comment: Thanks Tommy, but I think you've got that wrong. In I.6 of https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ it says that apps are meant to log the user out of facebook as well.

Comment: I just looked at the source code of the php sdk and it's generating a url the same as mine above (line 610 of https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php )

Comment: You are correct, good find! My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my access_token was invalid. I was storing it in a varchar(150) field, but newer tokens are now longer than that.

So the token was correct when used on the login page, but then on later pages (like logout) it was retrieved from the database and had been truncated, so it couldn't be decrypted by Facebook any more.

For reference, for anyone else, it doesn't look like there's a minimum length - 255 would work currently, 400 would be safer still, but the oauth spec allows any length, so a smalltext field would be needed to be completely safe.

Answer (score 1):

If the logout url takes you to https://www.facebook.com/home.php it means either the access token or the next url is incorrectly configured.

Try setting the next url to a nextt page (e.g. www.yourapp.com/logout.php) then from there redirect to your application.

Comment: If there was a problem with the next url I would expect it to still logout, but then stay on the facebook login page. But I don't think there is a problem as both the access-token and next-page have been working fine for the last 3 months. So it seems like it's something that has quietly changed on facebook's side.

Answer (score 0):

From Facebook's [SDK documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/) for logging out using Javascript:

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  // user is now logged out
})
```

`FB.logout` will log the user out of both your site and Facebook.

I recommend using the callback to redirect the user instead of a direct link to facebook.com/logout.php

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking at as my next option... just wondering why the php sdk is broken

Answer (score 0):

This also happen to me, I finally realized it is because I changed the web site place. I did update OAuth redirect URL to new place but forgot to changed the site address in basic setting....

1. Go to facebook app console
2. Go to Settings -> Basic. In Site URL type my new url

and logout url worked again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the domain of the page you are redirecting to in the Facebook App Settings

Settings -> Basic -> App Domains

But these domains have rules...

> App domains must match the domain of the Facebook Web Games URL (https), Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL.

If you want to have 2 different URLs then you can use both "Site URL" and "Secure Page Tab URL"

Settings -> Basic -> Website -> Site URL

Settings -> Basic -> Page Tab -> Secure Page Tab URL